# Invoking Message dialog from Settings Flyout causes Message Dialog to flicker

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to invoke messagedialog from setting flyout for my Windows 8 Metro app but it's causing the message dialog to flicker. Below is the code.

```cs
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {      
        SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested+=settings_CommandsRequested;
    }

    private void Settings_CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SetttingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
       SettingsCommand cmd = new SettingsCommand("test","test1232",new UICommandInvokedHandler(CreateDialog));
       args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(cmd);
    }

    private void CreateDialog(IUICommand command)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(command.Id, "cmd"))
        {
           MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Hi");
           md.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've contacted official microsoft dev-support and their response was:
"MessageDialog is not recommended within the SettingsFlyout".

So in case you want to implement something simillar to support user's decision from the SettingsPane, you should either:
1) Enable toggling feature in the Flyout.
2) Desiging the SettingsFlyout so it lets the user make decision (for example in Logout cases, add Yes/no buttons inside the settingsFlyout) - Thats the option I chose.